# Inline block for figure tag

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple gallery grid by using figure tag as one cell with a photo and its caption. I cannot make them align in a row with inline-block for some reason.

HTML:

```
<article class="gallery">

  <figure>
    <figcaption>
        Hello
    <figcaption>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>
      Hello
    <figcaption>    
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <figcaption>
      Hello
    <figcaption>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>

</article>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```css
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<article class="gallery">

  <figure>
    <figcaption>
        Hello
    <figcaption>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>
      Hello
    <figcaption>    
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <figcaption>
      Hello
    <figcaption>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>

</article>
```

The image still stays with the same dimensions.

Comment: use `img { width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `img { width: 100%; }`

```css
.gallery {
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="gallery">

  <figure>
    <figcaption>
        Hello
    <figcaption>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>
      Hello
    <figcaption>    
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <figcaption>
      Hello
    <figcaption>    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </figure>

</article>
```